# Connect to MySQL with EXCEL VBA problem, after I changed MySQL database directory

Tags: mysql, vba, connection-string

I have got a problem pertains to EXCEL VBA connect to MySQL database after I changed MySQL database location from default directory to new assigned direcotry. The code 100% works before this amendament. Now I press F8 fuction to excute code step by step and error occurs at connection statement as enclosed images. All your help will be highly appreciated.

error message is: excution error, code is -2147467259(80004005), automation error

Connection code is here:

```
myCon.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};" & _
           "Server=localhost;" & _
           "Database=tdcc;" & _
           "User=root;" & _
           "Password=root;" & _
           "Option=3;"
```

[Base Directory and Data Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeqWS.jpg)
[F8 Excution Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4CoJ.jpg)

Comment: Does your database data is successfully accessed using CLI after DB location change? What database location technique was used?

Comment: Dear Akina, from enclosed the first image "Base Directory and Data Directory" seems database could be connected by workbench. On the other hand, show databases could display all databases. Thanks.

Comment: ??? *after I changed MySQL database location from default directory to new assigned direcotry.* - clarify **this** phrase, please.

Comment: Dear Akina, thanks again. the default database location is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data. My system disk has limited space, that's why I changed the database location to D:\2202723\Documents\MySQL5.7\Data has enough space. Hope this is clear enough. Please check the enclosed image namely Base Directory and Data Directory for your reference.

Comment: *that's why I changed the database location to D:\2202723\Documents\MySQL5.7\Data* How do you do this? Detailed and precisely..

Comment: Tried my best to describe, firstly, turn on workbench/run services.msc to close service MYSQL57/create new directory  D:\2202723\Documents\MySQL5.7\Data /copy default data directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data to new direcotry /right click new directory to give "network services' full permission to access this directory/ update my.ini "datadir=D:\2202723\Documents\MySQL5.7\Data" /close workbench/ refresh services/ start services MYSQL57. I have checked connection is ok from reopen workbench. That's all. Many thanks.

Comment: Now, if you start mysql.exe (command-line client), does your data is accessed without problems via it?

Comment: Enter password: ****
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 26
Server version: 5.7.32-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

I entered password but seems OK.

Comment: I.e. you can perform SELECTs to your tables, and receive correct outputs?

Comment: Hi again, Because database tdcc is null now. select * from tdcc get nothing, everything goes fine without problem for your reference. Thanks.